# How to cache internal files in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express, pug

I have been using routing functions such as the following one to repeat the general layout(A.jade) of my website:

```
exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  res.render('A', {
     main: jade.renderFile('./views/B.jade')
  });
};
```

However, when I tried to cache the views:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.enable('view cache');
```

, it seemed that only A.jade was cached, whereas B.jade was rendered in realtime. I know this because I didn't have to restart the server when updating B.jade.

Is there a way for me to cache B.jade in this setup?

Beside views, how can we cache other resources such as CSS, JS, media files etc in the static public directory?

Comment: It's possible the jade is smart enough to check the modification date of B.jade and use the cache only if B.jade has not changed recently.  But, if B.jade has not changed, then it will use the cached version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cache variable

```
var cachedFiles = {};

exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  var file = './views/B.jade';
  cachedFiles[file] = cachedFiles[file] || jade.renderFile('./views/B.jade');
  res.render('A', {
     main: cachedFiles[file]
  });
};
```

if you need to add variables to your render function then use a memoize

```
npm install memoizee
```

then

```
var memoize = require('memoizee');

var memoizeRenderFile = memoize(jade.renderFile);

exports.overview = function(req, res, next) { 
  res.render('A', {
     main: memoizeRenderFile('./views/B.jade', {v:100})
  });
};
```

you can cache your static files easily using something like this, note you will need to npm install the below package

```
var staticCache = require('express-static-cache');

app.use(staticCache(__dirname + '/public'), {
  maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
})
```

IMO, theres really no need to cache your static files since they don't take up cpu much when reading the files asynchronously.  If you cache them, they will eat up memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention one thing in my original post. Sometimes I need to pass in an object to B.jade.　So the code may look like this: main: jade.renderFile('./views/B.jade',{v:100}). Can we account for this too?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment, i'll edit the answer. Basically you can achieve this using a memoize

Comment: Thanks! I will take look at the packages.